# Use Get-ODBCDSN remotely

Tags: powershell, odbc

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script that calls multiple remote machines and gathers the ODBC DSN User/System settings. I have the following script below however the `Get-ODBCDSN` cmdlet doesn't seem to have a property to retrieve the data remotely. Has anyone come across this issue and is able to offer some assistance?

```
$servers = @("SERVER1","SERVER2")
$DSNs  = @("DSN1","DSN2")

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    write-host `r`n "Getting DSN settings from "$server `r`n
    foreach ($DSN in $DSNs)
    {
        Get-ODBCDSN -name $DSN | Select Name, DsnType, platform, @{n='Description';e={$_.Attribute.server}}
        }
    Write-Output $results | sort name, dsntype
}
```

Comment: The typical method would be to use `Invoke-Command` with PS Remoting.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me but looks like now I'm having an issue running the command on an outside domain.

Comment: Yeah, that's a much larger rats nest because of how PS Remoting requires connections from trusted clients.  I'm afraid I've never worked on a setup that required that.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old and the answer is in the comments, but to make things a bit easier for future viewers to cut and paste...

```
$servers = @("SERVER1","SERVER2")
$dsns = @("DSN1","DSN2")
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  foreach ($dsn in $dsns) {
    Invoke-Command -computername $server -command {
      Get-ODBCDSN -name $dsn | 
        Select Name, DsnType, @{n='Description';e={$_.Attribute.server}}
    }
    Write-Output $results | sort name, dsntype
  }
}
```